# Convert a List<int> into a String in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have read a file and got myself a list of integers. For most of my work this is what I want to get, but in one case I also need to convert some of `List<int>` into a `String`.

To be more specified, I want to encode the string in UTF-8.

This is what I just tried:

```dart
var decoder = new Utf8Decoder(figures);
print(decoder.decodeRest());
```

But all I get is a list of integers.

Comment: suggestion. please edit this question to "convert a character code list into a string". looking for list<int> concatenation brought me here

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`String.fromCharCodes(List<int> charCodes)` is probably what you're looking for.

```dart
  List<int> charCodes = const [97, 98, 99, 100];
  print(new String.fromCharCodes(charCodes));
```

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer [No it's not.](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCodes.html)

Comment: @Abion47 thanks for the update. The answer and my comment are quite old. Not sure if there were changes in the meantime or I made a mistake.

Comment: In my condition, I have a list of type List<List<int>>
When I try to use above Code it throws error. How I can use above code for the list type
List<List<int>>. Your help will be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: This is NOT the correct answer, as this will corrupt any non ASCII char (for instance, diacritics, emojis, etc.). The correct answer should use `utf8.decode()`

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [dart:convert](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_convert.html) library which provides an [UTF-8 codec](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-convert/utf8-constant.html):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  List<int> charCodes = [97, 98, 99, 100];
  String result = utf8.decode(charCodes);
  print(result);
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. All the other solutions are very slow for longs strings.

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned `String.fromCharCodes(List<int> charCodes)` is likely what you are looking for if you want to convert unicode characters into a String. If however all you wanted was to merge the list into a string you can use `Strings.join(List<String> strings, String separator)`.

```dart
Strings.join([1,2,3,4].map((i) => i.toString()), ","))  // "1,2,3,4"
```

**Update (new Dart versions): Strings.join is no longer valid so you must use this instead:**

```dart
[1,2,3,4].map((i) => i.toString()).join(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dart:convert` library which provides an UTF-8 codec but be sure to use **utf8 all small** to use its methods.

```
List<int> byteArray = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100];
String result = utf8.decode(byteArray);
List<int> orginal = utf8.encode(result);
```