# How to convert List<int> to String in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have problem and dont know to solve.

`List<int> list= [1, 2, 3];`

How to convert list above into this:

`String data= '[1, 2, 3]';`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a List<int> into a String in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710459/convert-a-listint-into-a-string-in-dart)

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha in my case, i need to store my list<int> into txt file. Its require me using String to store

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I didn't know this worked well, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use toString() metohd.

```
 String data =  list.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this code

```
List<int> list= [1, 2, 3];String data  = list.toString().replaceAll('[', "'[").replaceAll(']',"]'");print(data);
```

you can try it on the dart pad to know the solution

Comment: Sneha G Sneha, I didn't realize that this also works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another way. Independent of the built-in 'toString()'.

```
void main() {
  final list = [1, 2, 3];
  final data = '[${list.join(', ')}]';
  print(data);
}
```